# Laravel Mix HMR Server Does Not Launch

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, laravel-mix, webpack-hmr

- Laravel Mix Version: 6.0.43
- Node Version (node -v): 16.13.1
- NPM Version (npm -v): 8.1.2
- OS: Windows 10 21h2

## Description:

THIS IS HAPPENING ON A FRESH NEW INSTALL OF LARAVEL AND MY OTHER PROJECTS

Running `npm run hot` changes the script tag sources to `http://localhost:8080/*/*.*` from `http://localhost/*/*.*` HOWEVER I always get `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` from `localhost:8080`. The HMR server doesn't launch at all. The terminal output of the command also have no mention of spinning up a new web server.

```
PS C:\Users\Eric Wang\Documents\GitHub\test-laravel-mix> npm run hot

● Mix █████████████████████████ emitting (95%)
 emit

● Mix █████████████████████████ done (99%) plugins
 WebpackBar:done



✔ Mix
  Compiled successfully in 5.51s


   Laravel Mix v6.0.43   


✔ Compiled Successfully in 5336ms
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┐├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤│                                                                                                        css/app.css │ 47.6 KiB │└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┘webpack compiled successfully
```

Here's a picture of the browser failing to fetch the bundle files

[image: screenshot]

## Steps To Reproduce:

I am running Docker 4.5.1 using legacy Hyper-V.
I containerized Laravel and PHP BUT not the frontend and JS. I am running Laravel Mix on my main system.

1. Clone the fresh installation of Laravel from https://github.com/ericwang401/test-laravel-mix
2. Clone Laradock in the project folder using git clone https://github.com/laradock/laradock.git
3. CD to the Laradock folder and make `.env` file with `cp .env.example .env`
4. Inside .env file set PHP_VERSION to PHP_VERSION=8.0 AND DO NOT EDIT MYSQL SETTINGS
5. Now edit the Laravel environment file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=default
DB_USERNAME=default
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

6. Start up the Laravel app in Laradock folder using `docker-compose up -d nginx mysql`
7. Enter into bash mode in the Docker container `docker-compose exec workspace bash`
8. Install Composer dependencies BUT NOT NPM DEPENDENCIES YET `composer i`
9. Now exit out of the Docker container `CNTRL + D`
10. Install NPM dependencies in project root ON YOUR MAIN SYSTEM `npm i`
11. Run on your main system `npm run hot`
12. Now go to `http://localhost` and IT SHOULD be a white screen
13. Check console logs and it should give `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` when it tries to fetch the bundle files

REMEMBER: the backend is running inside Docker
The frontend (Laravel Mix) is running on the host system

This issue is happening on a FRESH project installation of Laravel 9 + Jetstream AND it's also happening on my other older projects like https://github.com/StratumPanel/Stratum-Panel

The HMR server is simply not launching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue. The problem was that the default port, 8080, Laravel Mix HMR was using couldn't be binded to. Webpack Dev Server doesn't respond with a message of failing to bind to a port. To confirm this issue, I replicated the environment on my friend's PC and it too couldn't bind to port 8080, but this time it reported an error that the dev server couldn't bind to port 8080.

I fixed this issue by specifying

```
mix.options({
        hmrOptions: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 4206
        }
    });
```

And it works! On both my friend's pc and my pc.

I used the exact same reproduction instructions on my friend's PC.

*I spent way too long investigating this issue*

Comment: I couldn't figure out why some of the debug lines when running `npm run hot` was showing `[wds] ....` and some of them were not. When WDS could boot up the server it shows the info that where it is running, in which port. if it cannot boot the server, it doesn't show those messages. That's how the next person reaching here will be able to figure it out. Also, this article maybe helpful for someone else. https://imranhsayed.medium.com/webpack-dev-server-b1010d01dba5